# itms-services // action=download-manifest url as local file

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to utilize:

itms-services // action=download-manifest url as local file, is there any standard way of utilizing plist file via that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this done in an app that aided with OTA app updating for developers; what I saw in the source code was that a file:// link was used. If you want to do this, you'd have to know the location of the file in the filesystem. Then, you'd use a standard plist file, but in the url key, you'd put file://location/to/your/ipa/file and it would essentially be the same. 
Though, that isn't the best way of doing things, because it is an unknown whether the user has the ipa file on their device or not.

Comment: Thanks user, I will give a shot tomorrow morning, and see if that works.

Comment: You might want a jailbroken device at hand to find to location of the ipa in the filesystem... Just a suggestion. Anyways, let me know after you've tried.